# Upgrading Nginx 1.1.9 to 1.4.x

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have a production server running Nginx 1.1.9 (on Ubuntu 12.04). I would like to upgrade it to The latest stable version of Nginx. I'm having some trouble finding out how and if upgrading will have some backwards compatibility issues. I have multiple sites running and altered config files etc.

What should I expect when upgrading?

Comment: nothing programing related, belongs to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Nginx allows very graceful upgrade procedure. You should read the article: http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#upgrade

As for the guide about API changes, you can find all of them in change log under the `Change:` keyword: http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES